# Variable-Sized GridViewItem in GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8, winrt-xaml

In a GridView (Windows 8 App), I use the following item template to show the items :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ProjectTemplate">
    <Grid Width="500" Background="MidnightBlue">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="20, 10" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="WhiteSmoke"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20, 10, 10, 10" Background="MidnightBlue">
            <TextBlock Text="Last Modified :" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Foreground="WhiteSmoke"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastModified}" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Foreground="WhiteSmoke"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding VideoPath}" Margin="20, 10, 10, 10" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="WhiteSmoke"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

So, mainly, it is a `Grid` with three rows showing data binded for Name, LastModified and VideoPath properties of my `Project` item the `GridView` deals with. The items are retrieved correctly, the binding is OK, my problem is more a matter of... design.

Here's an example :

[image]

If you notice, the first two items, seem OK - they have the `Name`, `LastModified` Date and `VideoPath` shown. The third item, on the other hand, has a longer `Name` shown in a `TextBlock` with `TextWrapping=true`, and the `VideoPath` is omitted when shown. Also the third textblock for the `VideoPath` has the TextWrapping set.

Is there any way I could enlarge the grid for each item individual according to its needs to show the full content? What modifications I need to make to the template?

**Edit**

I didn't want to set the Height explicitly, because in that case, GridViewItems (in which the the textblocks' text is short enough for one row), will be larger and have... empty areas (sorry for bad explanation, but I really can't find my words to put it better)...

Answer (score 0):

Altough I searched a lot for Variable-Sized items, and found many... complicated solutions, I came across a very easy one.

`WinRT XAML Toolkit` has this nice `WrapPanel` which did all the job in my case. Instead of the `Grid`, in the Template, I used the `WrapPanel`, and in the GridView's `ItemPanelTemplate` as well :

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

The result looks like this : [image]

Comment: You found a working solution, but from a UX perspective it may be a better design to have items of uniform size and then truncate the text (using ellipses) or leave enough room for two lines of text and have extra space for the items that only need one line of text for the title.  But, it's your call of course :) .